Order Records by json/hash column's key
I'm having a scenario where I need to perform sorting based on hash/json's key.
To make it clearer, TableA has three columns:
col1 -> vendor_name(type: string)
col2 ->store_name(type: string)
col3 -> fruits(type: json/jsonb)

Sample data: id: 1, vendor_name: 'abc', store_name: 'fresh_fruits', fruits: {'apple': 10, orange: 12, grapes: 10, pineapple: 13}

Use case: Need to sort store based on fruit counts stored in the hash (by the way, we can simply move these fruits' names to a separate column, but this is just sample use case whereas in mine I have dynamic addition of columns so I went for storing data like).
Im newbie Rails developer, any solutions/recommendations are kindly invited :)

You didn't specify the desired sorting order precisely.

It Will be both acs/desc order, dynamically it changes when user clicks the arrow icon in ui (Used datatables for that)
